# How can I write a variable number of if statements? (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

Quite simply how would one write the following for the case where x is any positive integer starting from 1?

```
if x == 1:
    n = 1
elif 2 <= x <= 5:
    n = 2
elif 6 <= x <= 9:
    n = 3
elif 10 <= x <= 13:
    n = 4
elif 14 <= x <= 17:
    n = 5
```

...and so on...

Answer (score 8):

You don't need `if` or a loop, it's a simple, closed-form mathematical relation:

```
n = 2 + (x - 2)/4
```

BTW, you don't need to test both ends of the ranges in your `elif` statements. Since they're executed in order, you know that the number is greater than the bottom of the range, so it would just be:

```
if x == 1:
    n = 1
elif x <= 5:
    n = 2
elif x <= 9:
    n = 3
... and so on
```

Comment: Or `(x - 2) / 4 + 2`? I think your expression returns 4 for `x = 14`

Comment: Barmar - thank you for your reply but this does not return the correct values eg. for x = 10, n = 3 using your code.

Comment: I had a mistake in my original formula, try it now.

Comment: No, (10 - 2) / 4 + 2 = 4, as expected. The function behaves separately for `x = 1` and other `x`s. Your new formula returns `n = 2` for `x = 1`. I think `x=1` is a special case outside the closed form

Comment: Thanks, @SudeepJuvekar Your formula is best.

Comment: Barmar - might be because I'm new here but your code has gone! Am I being stupid or is there some delay before it updates?

Comment: Not sure what's happening, try refreshing.

Comment: Sudeep Juvekar:
I just used your formula and keep getting x = 5 for n = 10?

Comment: I deleted my response, thinking @Barmar is editing his. I am wrong, `x  = 1` is not a special case. I'll delete my post, let's keep one solid response.

Comment: @user3394391 If you're trying to send a comment to a specific user, remember to put `@` before their name so they'll be notified. This also enables auto-complete, so you can type `@su<tab>` and it will finish the name.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! Would you be able to post your solution in here as things don't seem to be displaying very well :s Sorry to be a pain. Thank you to everyone who has helped!

Comment: For future reference is this question I asked a bad one? Downvoted straight away.